# How do install POEdit on CentOS 7?

Tags: installation, autoconf, autotools, poedit

I want to install POEdit on CentOS 7.

After running `./configure`, I receive a message about several libraries not being installed, such as wxWidgets and Boost. I've installed these libraries and it moves past that phase of the configuration, but now it's saying that the LUCENE library is not available. So I've downloaded, compiled and installed the Lucene++ library, but does not resolve the problem. Any ideas?

Here is the transacript:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for install location... /usr/local
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=gnu++11... yes
checking for wx-config... /usr/local/bin/wx-config
checking for wxWidgets version >= 3.0.0 (--unicode)... yes (version 3.0.1)
checking for wxWidgets static library... no
checking if wxWidgets includes XRC... yes
checking for wxrc... /usr/local/bin/wxrc-3.0
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking boost/function.hpp usability... yes
checking boost/function.hpp presence... yes
checking for boost/function.hpp... yes
checking for mkdtemp... yes
checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for ICU... yes
checking if wxWidgets toolkit uses GTK+ 3... no
checking if wxWidgets toolkit uses GTK+ 2... yes
checking for GTKSPELL... no
configure: WARNING: disabling spellchecking because GtkSpell is missing
checking for Berkeley DB >= 4.7 (C++)... header db_cxx.h, library -ldb_cxx
checking for LUCENE... no
configure: error: missing Lucene++ library
```

Answer (score 2):

You installed the Lucene c++ library, it's [LucenePlusPlus](https://github.com/luceneplusplus/LucenePlusPlus) ?

I've cloned the repository and installed it, then installed Poedit without any problem. It's the version 3.0.6

Check the output from the install of the port to see the paths